# How to dampen resonant noise in laundry standpipe?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a standing drain pipe behind the laundry machine.  It's 2 inch PVC about 3 or 4 feet high with a trap at floor level.   The water draining from the machine creates noise inside the pipe that gets amplified by the plastic pipe and is annoying.

The old machine had a sealed connection to the standpipe, and the water came out in a constant flow that would get the water in the trap flowing along.   The new machine is "HE" and emits drain water in little dribbles that just fall onto the sitting trap water, creating the noise.  The new machine hose also is not sealed where it joins the standpipe, which I believe is correct but this helps make the noise louder.

The main problem is the resonance of the pipe itself.

How can I reduce the noise coming from the standpipe?

I'm thinking of trying some dampening, like wrapping the pipe with rubber but not sure what material to use or how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Swap the hoses from the old machine to the new one so there's a seal at the stand pipe and extend the washer hose with 3 or 4 feet of hose or tubing so it almost breaks the surface of the water in the trap.

Comment: The extended hose by itself would do the trick I bet.  Good idea.

Comment: I thought sealing the hose to the standpipe was both against code and could create siphon problems, potentially in both directions.  And I thought code also requires a minimum gap between hose and trap and the plastic hook that comes with the washing machine was meant to ensure that gap?   Otherwise, shoving the hose further down and sealing the top with a reducing fernco or just a hunk of foam would be an easy solution.

Comment: I was assuming (foolish me) that the old "sealed" drain hose was by design from the manufacturer, maybe with some air gap. If it's a hack, then no.  The length of extending the hose would be an experiment but just make sure the end is above the waterline of the trap.  I have seen many that were sealed with no problems and not sealed with problems.

Comment: The old sealed drain was by design from the old manufacturer but it was 20+ years old.    I agree you can have problems or no problems both ways.  Maybe I'll experiment.